# Port forwarding on a Linksys RV016

Tags: apache-2.2, port-forwarding

We have a small web application on our network that we need to make available for a few people through the internet.

I thought port forwarding to the webserver would be simple enough, but when I try to access the IP (204.34.??.254, for example), I get the login prompt for the switch.

What could be the problem?

Sorry if it sounds like some dumb question, but I have no knowledge of networks, my focus has always been coding, and the IT support staff doesn´t know what is the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

Check on which port the admin-panel is running. If this is also on port 80, change it to something else like 8080.

If you configured NAT the right way, you should be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in the end the problem was between chair and keyboard.

Comment: I spoke too soon. No matter what I do or which port I try to use, I get a login prompt from the switch, unless I´m already logged in, which masked my last try as a sucess.

Comment: A few questions: What is the internal IP of the webserver? What happens if you change the port of the networkapp to 8080 and pass it along? Does it work OK internally?

Comment: The internal IP is 130.2.28.53. It works perfectly internally.

Comment: Trying to use ports 8080, or even 81 still worked internally, but the switch still asked for its login for its control panel.

Comment: How can an internal IP be 130.0.0.0/8 ? Are you sure this is the external IP? Shouldn't it be in a C-class network (ex: 192.168.0.0/16; 10.0.0.0/8 )?

Comment: Why can´t it be 130.0.0.0/8? As I said above, I have no real knowledge of networks, with all my focus being on coding. The only IT staff there is pretty much only for user support and maintenance on the desktops.

Comment: Because if you would use 130.2.28.53 as an internal IP, several internet-locations (in the 130.0.0.0/8 would be unavailable). THe IP resolves to a location in the US (AT&T network). I even think it is possible that the switch (or router with NAT as I understand) will most likely not allow you to do this...

Comment: Well, I wasn´t the one who configured the network. It was already there when I joined. And I don´t think blocking access to internet was a concern for whoever did it. For all I know they intended to at first.